# Splitting a single particle wave function

Tags: quantum-mechanics, double-slit-experiment

The wikipedia article on the double slit experiment contains the following animation:
https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/transcoded/a/a0/Double_slit_experiment.webm/Double_slit_experiment.webm.180p.vp9.webm

Here we can see that part of the wavefunction is reflected back at the electron source. Does this only happen when there are multiple particles? If the experiment is set up so that at any one time, there is at most 1 electron between the electron source and the screen, can this sort of reflection still happen?

More generally: what happens when a wave function of a single particle splits in two parts, with each part propagating in a different direction? Is this even possible?

Comment: I have supplied an answer. However, I do not know why you are thinking what you are thinking, so I was not able to really go any deeper. If you update with your thought process I might be able to go deeper though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does this only happen when there are multiple particles?

No. Wave function reflection can happen with single-particle wave functions.

> what happens when a wave function of a single particle splits in two parts, with each part propagating in a different direction? Is this even possible?

Yes, this is possible. It just means that there is some probability of finding the particle at various locations in space along those directions.

Comment: So technically the wave function of a single particle could consist of two parts arbitrarily far away from each other?

Comment: @Eric Yes, that is correct

Answer (score 1):

When a single electron is fired it will not give the full probability function that you see in the animation, in fact there are other paths of low probability that are not even shown. Any particle has a chance of going anywhere, that's why we can say a single particle many has possible paths or wave functions. The single path that a particle ultimately takes is a different wave funtion than the probability one shown in the animation which tries to show ~ >99% of the probable paths.